# Wygwam and modal windows for images

Tags: assets, jquery, wygwam, modal

This issue has come up several times in the past with clients, and I can't seem to think up a clever way of doing it.  A few of my clients would like to upload images in the body copy of their text that will popup a jQuery modal window with a larger version of the image when clicked on, rather than a new tab/window default behavior.

This would probably be easy if they were limited to one image in the body, but I don't want to limit them with just one image... and plus I'm very curious if this can be done ;-)  If it matters, I'll be using Assets as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I guess there are several ways of doing this, one of them is finding a way to *modify* preferences window (target or similiar) of a link. But I found it much easer instruct clients to add css class to the link they make.

They make a normal link to big image they want to open in modal window, and in Advanced tab they add special css class. Based on that class you make js call to your modal window, fancybox etc.

This can be easy included in documentation and can be actually used on all channels.

[image]

Comment: If this solves your question, please mark it as a answer. thanx :)